# httpclient proxy not working C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-4.5

I am trying to use the proxy with httpclient request.

```
        string proxystring = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3128/";                        
        HttpClientHandler handler2 = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler2.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxystring, false);
        handler2.UseProxy = true;
        HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(handler2);
```

Proxy settings are ignored and its not working.
Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you determine that proxy settings are ignored? Your code seems to work for me.

Comment: when i insert fake proxy in the proxy string the application still work